# How to update the UI during the doInBackground portion of a thread?

Tags: android

I have a time consuming task that is taking place in the doInBackground() method, but from within that method, I want to be able to update the progressDialog with percentage data. How can I do this?

```
    class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {     

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),Constants.APP_NAME,"Getting data", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        //go get data, update mProgressDialog
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
    {           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask has method `onProgressUpdate(Integer...)` that you can call each iteration for example or each time a progress is done during `doInBackground()` by calling `publishProgress()`.

Refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for more details

---

Note that the second parameter is the progress variable

```
class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {     

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),Constants.APP_NAME,"Getting data", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        publishProgress(""+(int)count);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        /**
         * Sets current progress on ProgressDialog
         */
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
    {           

    }
}
```

Comment: but how does AsyncTask know how far along it is, what is the measuring stick so to speak?

Comment: measuring unit? you can do it whatever you like, like the `alreadydownloaded/sizeoffile`, simple `43/100 %`, whatever you want it to display and update :)

Answer (score 2):

Override the  onProgressUpdate() method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
}
```

and publish the progress with

```
publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
```

Try to refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)